# Unable to delete user profiles with pictures

Tags: user-profile, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

When I try to delete user profiles with profile pictures from SharePoint 2019 central administration I get "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you". Profiles without pictures can be deleted.

If I first delete the profile picture from the library and remove the picture from the profile I can delete the profile.

What additional permissions are required to remove the profiles with pictures?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following:

- Ensure you have "Manage Profiles" permission on the User Profile Service Application?
- Do you have site collection administrator rights?
- If the profile pictures are stored in a SharePoint library, you might need permissions to delete items from this library.
- You might need admin permissions for both Azure Active Directory and Exchange Online to remove user photos.

See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-user-profiles

And: https://www.process.st/how-to/remove-users-from-sharepoint/

And (CodeTwo third-party tool): https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365/user-photos-in-o365/m-p/729395

Try and let me know if this fixes things.

Comment: I have "manage profiles" permission, site collection admin rights for the users mysite, site collection admin rights for the site collection where the pictures are stored.
The pictures are only in SharePoint, no connection to AD.

Comment: SharePoint might not reflect the changes immediately due to caching. Clearing the distributed cache might help. Ensure that the User Profile Synchronization service is running correctly. If there’s a sync issue, it might prevent the deletion of user profiles. Users might get orphaned in SharePoint. These are users that are referenced somewhere in the site collection, but they do not actually exist in the site collection’s User Information List. You might need to remove these orphaned users. Finally try using PowerShell to delete the user profiles.

Comment: You can use a combination of SharePoint and Exchange PowerShell commands. `Remove-UserPhoto -Identity "<user's email address>"` and then `$upa = Get-SPServiceApplication | ? {$_.TypeName -match "profile"}` then
`Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $upa -PurgeNonImportedObjects $true`